# is there a utility to automatically find 64bit versions of installed 32bit software?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I migrated from Vista 32bit to Windows 7 64bit and moved my apps with PCmover. I have also upgraded Eclipse to the 64bit version.

Is there a utility (like [AppSnap](http://appsnap.genotrance.com/)) that will automatically find 64bit versions of my 32bit apps?

I have gotten 3 useless off-topic answers at [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/technology/information-technology/computers-software/TCH_ITS_CMP/818000-1961580)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't due to the reason that you can just go to the Software Vendor's website to see if they have a 64 bit application for download, if not then you'll need to stick with the 32 bit version.

There are at times where I can get picky and want to utilize the use for my 64 bit os but like you just have to live with the 32 bit mode for some programs.

Mainly programs that get constantly updated usually have 64 bit support, but it's up to the software vendor if they wish to compile it for the 64 bit OS.

Comment: Actually there isn't because either someone has not posted one or one has not been coded by anyone, yet.